# How to highlight a selected date in FullCalendar.js

Tags: fullcalendar, momentjs

I would like to highlight a selected date.

ex: i already clicked a date and the selected date is inserted in the textbox,now again i clicked the calendar, now the date in the textbox should highlight in the calendar.
Im able to highlight the selected date in dayClick, but couldn't highlight it when he is back to calendar to change the option.

Can someone help me.!

```
dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) { 
$(".fc-state-highlight").removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
$("td[data-date=" + date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "]").addClass("fc-state-highlight");}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my previous answer is not correct.
Change your code line:

```
$("td[data-date=" + date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "]").addClass("fc-state-highlight");
```

to this:

```
$('.fc-day[data-date="' + date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '"]').addClass("fc-state-highlight");
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you Asator for your reply
based on your answer i could able to solve in this way

```
dayRender: function (date, element, view) {                    
var dateString = moment(displayDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
view.el.find('.fc-day-number[data-date="' + dateString + '"]').css('background-color', '#3276b1');                                     
}
```